# Showing an Image on a masterpage based on the logged in user

Tags: asp.net-mvc

So I have a masterpage that has an image whos source is a controller action returning a filestream.

The image will be different for each logged in user.

right now in my masterpage view i have this code wich relies on viewdata.

```
  <img id="dealerlogo" src='/Files/DealerImage/GetDealerLogo/<%=Html.Encode(ViewData["dealerid"]) %>' alt="" />
```

obviously the problem with this is that I will need to provide the viewdata containing the ID
on everycontroller action returning a view that uses this master page, which is pretty much all of them.
Is there a better way to do this? Like is there a way to get the username right in the view?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Page.User.Identity.Name just like in the default logonusercontrol.aspx that is created for you when you create a new asp.net MVC site.

```
Welcome <b><%= Html.Encode(Page.User.Identity.Name ) %></b>
```

So for you, you would want something like this:

```
  <img id="dealerlogo" src='/Files/DealerImage/GetDealerLogo/<%=Html.Encode(Page.User.Identity.Name) %>' alt="" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily encapsulate this logic in a `[ChildActionOnly]` Action that returns a partial view and then use new MVC 2 approach

```
 <% Html.RenderAction("GetUserPhoto", "User"); %>
```

to have it everywhere in your view pages without passing ViewData in all actions.

Here's the solution:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult GetUserPhoto()
{
    ViewData["UserId"] = Page.User.Identity;
    return PartialView();
}
```

And in your view you use the same logic you used to show user image. Also you can directly send a FileResult to partial view to render image for you. In this approach you don't need to repeat `ViewData["XXXX"]` in all views and you need just to Render the new Partial View in your main Views.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your GetDealerLogo action method has a parameter of dealerid. It's better to write something like:

```
<img src="<%= Url.Action("GetDealerLogo", "DealerImage", new { dealerid = ViewData["dealerid"] }) %>" />
```

Nothing wrong with passing it in via ViewData. You might also consider a [strongly-typed View](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2009/04/13/asp-net-mvc-tip-50-ndash-create-view-models) or your own [ViewPage base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370500/inheriting-from-viewpage) which exposes a DealerId property.

To make it even cleaner, I really like [T4MVC](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC). It would allow you to write:

```
<img src="<%= Url.Action(MVC.DealerImage.GetDealerLogo(dealerid)) %>" />
```

And, even further, you might create an [Html helper](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs), so you can write:

```
<%= Html.DealerLogo(dealerid) %>
```